# MVC5 Windows Authentication works in IISExpress but not for IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication, iis-8

Same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248151/windows-authentication-works-in-iisexpress-but-not-in-iis) but it was not a solution for me, its been more than 16 hours I'm trying to find solution for it.

I setup Windows Authentication for my MVC5 (ASP.Net Fw4.5) application using VS2013 (Windows Server 2012 R2) following are the major steps i did for setting up.

- I have two controllers I put Authorize attribute on Home controller, About controller does not have any attribute on it
- On project properties Enabled Windows Authentication
- Web.Config as below

  ```
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
     <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>

  <identity impersonate="false" />    

  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  ```
- IIS Settings
- Anonymous Authentication is Enabled
- Windows Authentication is Enabled (Provider: NTLM, Negotiate)

With these configurations my application works perfect on IISExpress, but when I access it through IIS it prompts for login/password upon giving correct username/password it keep repeating. (I can access About Controller without Authorize attribute)

I inspected request through Fiddler that bring something interesting.  Below is the response when i access through IIS

[image]

When i access through IISExpress i can see there are three entries for single request two of them get 401 but third gets 200

[image]

Comment: Try to use a proper site binding so that you can access the IIS site from another machine, and let us know if that works.

Comment: You can try enabling Kerberos logging and see what it says: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/262177/how-to-enable-kerberos-event-logging